# What's causing my c# WinForms application to freeze / hang?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have a .Net 2.0 C# WinForms application that runs fine in development but occasionally freezes in production. I have looked for all the usual culprits:
1. I've used InvokeRequired and Invoke to make sure that no UI components are manipulated from the wrong thread.
2. I've synchronized all my timer objects on the UI thread.
3. I've read this article http://www.ikriv.com/en/prog/info/dotnet/MysteriousHang.html about OnUserPreferenceChanged and I did have this problem, but I fixed it.

This started happening when we migrated from .Net 1.1 to .Net 2+. Before that, it never hang.

I'm using Managed Stack Explorer to periodically get stack traces from the production application when this problem occurs and the main UI thread is always stuck in some new random place. It's not blocked on WaitOne as you might expect if this were a thread deadlock.

My application does these things:
- Uses multiple System.Timers.Timer instances.
- Uses WMI to manage printing.
- Has a few background threads that make Web Services calls to a server, but do not interact with the UI.
- Has a few background thread that use System.Diagnostics.Process to look at other processes on the computer and sometimes kill them.
- Interacts with a 3rd party dll that uses the serial port to talk to a bill acceptor.
- Interacts with some com/activex/ocx controls to interact with a credit card reader.

Here's an example of one time it hang and all the stack traces at the time:

```
Thread ID: 2816  
    0. System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne (Source Unavailable)
    1. System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne (Source Unavailable)
    2. System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne (Source Unavailable)
    3. System.Management.MTAHelper.WorkerThread (Source Unavailable)
    4. System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context (Source Unavailable)
    5. System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (Source Unavailable)
    6. System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart (Source Unavailable)

Thread ID: 2828  

Thread ID: 2852  
    0. MeiNet.EBDS.BillAcceptor.submitRequestStack (Source Unavailable)
    1. MeiNet.EBDS.BillAcceptor.OnHandleEscrowed (Source Unavailable)
    2. MeiNet.EBDS.BillAcceptor.EventHandler (Source Unavailable)

Thread ID: 2908  

Thread ID: 2820  
    0. System.Threading.Thread.Sleep (Source Unavailable)
    1. MyApp.ProcessKiller.startSpecialKillerLoop (ProcessKiller.cs:115)
    2. System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context (Source Unavailable)
    3. System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (Source Unavailable)
    4. System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart (Source Unavailable)

Thread ID: 2600  

Thread ID: 2844  
    0. System.Threading.Thread.Start (Source Unavailable)
    1. System.Net.TimerThread.Prod (Source Unavailable)
    2. System.Net.TimerThread.TimerQueue.CreateTimer (Source Unavailable)
    3. System.Net.ServicePoint..ctor (Source Unavailable)
    4. System.Net.ServicePointManager.FindServicePointHelper (Source Unavailable)
    5. System.Net.ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint (Source Unavailable)
    6. System.Net.HttpWebRequest.FindServicePoint (Source Unavailable)
    7. System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream (Source Unavailable)
    8. System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke (Source Unavailable)
    9. MyApp.MyServer.Server.hb4 (Reference.cs:588)
    10. MyApp.HeartbeatSender.SendThreadedHeartbeat (HeartbeatSender.cs:81)
    11. MyApp.HeartbeatSender.StartHeartbeatLoop (HeartbeatSender.cs:40)
    12. System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context (Source Unavailable)
    13. System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (Source Unavailable)
    14. System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart (Source Unavailable)

Thread ID: 2824  
    0. System.Threading.Thread.Sleep (Source Unavailable)
    1. MyApp.OfficeMonitor.StartMonitoring (OfficeMonitor.cs:84)
    2. System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context (Source Unavailable)
    3. System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (Source Unavailable)
    4. System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart (Source Unavailable)

Thread ID: 2584  
    0. [Internal thisFrame, 'M-->U', System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods::GetModuleHandle] (Source Unavailable)
    1. System.Windows.Forms.Application.get_ComCtlSupportsVisualStyles (Source Unavailable)
    2. System.Windows.Forms.ButtonInternal.ButtonStandardAdapter.PaintWorker (Source Unavailable)
    3. System.Windows.Forms.ButtonInternal.ButtonStandardAdapter.PaintUp (Source Unavailable)
    4. System.Windows.Forms.ButtonInternal.ButtonStandardAdapter.PaintOver (Source Unavailable)
    5. System.Windows.Forms.ButtonInternal.ButtonBaseAdapter.Paint (Source Unavailable)
    6. System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.OnPaint (Source Unavailable)
    7. System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling (Source Unavailable)
    8. System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint (Source Unavailable)
    9. System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc (Source Unavailable)
    10. System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc (Source Unavailable)
    11. System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc (Source Unavailable)
    12. System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage (Source Unavailable)
    13. System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc (Source Unavailable)
    14. System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback (Source Unavailable)
    15. [Internal thisFrame, 'M-->U', System.Windows.Forms.SafeNativeMethods::UpdateWindow] (Source Unavailable)
    16. System.Windows.Forms.Control.Update (Source Unavailable)
    17. System.Windows.Forms.Control.Refresh (Source Unavailable)
    18. MyApp.MainForm.ClearFields (MainForm.cs:4057)
    19. MyApp.MainForm.ShowHomeButtons (MainForm.cs:5664)
    20. MyApp.MainForm.ShowScreenSaver (MainForm.cs:4284)
    21. MyApp.MainForm.ScreensaverTimerTick (MainForm.cs:7817)
    22. System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast (Source Unavailable)
    23. System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke (Source Unavailable)
    24. System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl (Source Unavailable)
    25. System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo (Source Unavailable)
    26. System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper (Source Unavailable)
    27. System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode (Source Unavailable)
    28. System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (Source Unavailable)
    29. System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (Source Unavailable)
    30. System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback (Source Unavailable)
    31. System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks (Source Unavailable)
    32. System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc (Source Unavailable)
    33. System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc (Source Unavailable)
    34. System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc (Source Unavailable)
    35. System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc (Source Unavailable)
    36. System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage (Source Unavailable)
    37. System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc (Source Unavailable)
    38. System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback (Source Unavailable)
    39. [Internal thisFrame, 'M-->U', System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods::DispatchMessageW] (Source Unavailable)
    40. System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop (Source Unavailable)
    41. System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner (Source Unavailable)
    42. System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop (Source Unavailable)
    43. System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run (Source Unavailable)
    44. MyApp.MainForm.Main (MainForm.cs:2975)
```

Any suggestions on what I ought to do?

Comment: With hang do you mean a user interface that isn't responding anymore? Or is there some errormessage shown?

Comment: @Nobody I don't think anyone can give you any advice on what is specifically causing you app to hang without seeing all of the code (which is way out of the scope of SO).

Comment: Deadlock doesn't just occur when you tell something to wait.  If you're locking something, and another thread goes to lock it, that can cause deadlock, if a method relies on something it hasn't initialized yet and that needs a lock it can cause deadlock.  etc. etc. etc.  Be *super* careful when you use threads.

Comment: There is no error message. The UI just becomes unresponsive.

Comment: I should add that this hang started happening after we migrated from .Net 1.1 to .Net 2+. It never happened before that.

Comment: I can't think of any scenario where GetModuleHandle() could deadlock.  If that's consistently on the top-of-stack for the UI thread then it is most likely environmental.

Comment: I had a similar problem on WinForms. The problem gone after I replaced Invoke with BeginInvoke.

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts:

- Are you using any preprocessor flags in your Development environment that don't exist in production. So any `#If Debug` or whatever.
- Have you been testing on the development environment in release mode? Does it still not hang?
- What's different about the Machines? Does one have more RAM, a quad-core vs. dual-core, is one behind a million firewalls and the other not?
- In your threading are you sure nothing is ever waiting on some call back to finish before updating a UI element?
- Are you using databases? If so are they different ones and how are they different?
- Is the hanging maybe caused by the fact that you are pulling StackTraces?
- Are there any exceptions that you are swallowing anywhere that may be telling you what is happening?
- Is there something different about the Serial Port on the machines?
- Is the same bill receptor being used?

Continue and so on.

Try installing this on a fresh VM and see what happens. It could be some old dll or driver, most of the time when `Works on my machine` symptoms happen it's because there was something you did that you forgot about that made things work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Quick answers: No flags, No different modes, I'll check the hw, no threads are awaiting callbacks, no database, didn't start getting stacktraces until having this problem, logging all exceptions, I'll check the serial ports, We'll check the acceptors. Thanks again for thinking about this.

Answer (score 1):

We had the exact same problem, and this article (like you mentioned) pointed us to the solution:
http://www.ikriv.com/dev/dotnet/MysteriousHang.html#WhatToDo

We used a splash screen with the following code:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((x) =>
{
    using (var splashForm = new SplashForm())
    {
        splashForm.Show();
        while (!done)
            Application.DoEvents();
        splashForm.Close();
    }
});
```

We had the luck we could reproduce the deadlock. We have a laptop/tablet where you can detach the screen from the keyboard so you have a tablet only. Every time we detached the screen, our application hung. After removing the splash our problem was gone.

We had the exact same stack trace from the hanging program by the way:

```
System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne (Source Unavailable)
1. System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne (Source Unavailable)
2. System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne (Source Unavailable)
3. System.Management.MTAHelper.WorkerThread (Source Unavailable)
4. System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context (Source Unavailable)
5. System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (Source Unavailable)
6. System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart (Source Unavailable)
```

Offcourse I don't know if your problem has the same cause/solution... But this did it for us.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a similar-looking hang, where one thread was making that call to Application.get_ComCtlSupportsVisualStyles .

I wonder if you have enabled visual styles?  http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/05/05/599.aspx describes how to do it using either code or manifest file.  (I think the manifest file is the preferred solution.)

If you get visual styles enabled, and assuming the OS supports themes (I think this feature started with XP), then Application.get_ComCtlSupportsVisualStyles does not have to do nearly as much work, and can return true quickly.

All that said, I still don't understand why the call to GetModuleHandle() would hang.  Most of what I have found on the web about indicates it would be a problem during LoadLibrary(), not during a .NET Win Forms paint event.  I don't know if maybe you have another thread that is at the same time doing unsafe work in LoadLibrary()...?